# How can I run a .bat file with parameter in NSIS installer

Tags: batch-file, nsis

I am trying to write a script which run a mysqlimport_create_database.bat file with parameter.

script of batch file `C:\"Program Files (x86)"\jasperreports-server-cp-4.0.0\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root -p  < create_database.sql`

So when I run this batch file,it asks for password, I want to add a parameter for password.

My NSIS script to run batch file and pass a password as a parameter

```
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\mysqlimport_create_database.bat" "password"'
```

How can i pass the password as a parameter?

Comment: Just so I don't answer the wrong thing; do you mean how you can pass it from NSIS or how the bat file can use it?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I think in the end it will nail down to *‘How can I pass the password to `mysql.exe`?’*.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have solved the problem, the problem was in batch file we can add password also in same batch file ,like this--if the password is "root"  C:\"Program Files (x86)"\jasperreports-server-cp-4.0.0\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root -proot < create_database.sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, the problem was in batch file we can add password also in same batch file ,like this--if the password is "root" C:\"Program Files (x86)"\jasperreports-server-cp-4.0.0\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root -proot < create_database.sql

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parameter within the batch program using "%1"